# Android: Layout cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this mainactivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

//Array of options --> ArrayAdapter --> ListView

//List view: {views: list_items.xml}


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    populateListView();
}
private void populateListView() {
    //Create list of items
    String[] myItems = {"Blue", "Green", "Purple", "Red"};

    //Build Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this                   //Context for the activity
            R.layout.list_items,   //Layout to use (Create)
            myItems);              //Items to be displayed

    //Configure the ListView
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    ViewPager myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    myViewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    myViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch(pos) {

        case 2: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
        case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
        case 0: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
        default: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Default");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }       


    {}}}
```

I am trying to add a listview, i have created a xml file called: list_items.xml, but on this line: "R.layout.list_items," i get an error: "layout cannot be resolved or is not a field" and i also get "syntax error on token "R", delete this token". Why is that?

The list_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


 </TextView>
```

Comment: Is this an `R` question? Can you please check the tag [R] to confirm?

Comment: it is about `R` ressource file in android, not about r language. I removed tag. @asb

Comment: sorry about the r tag my bad :)

Comment: Error in your XML file most likely, so the R file cannot be generated

Comment: @fisher3421 still same error :/

Comment: @da_st Can put list_items.xml?

Comment: @da_st do you have any other xml file? if so please check it for errors, usually if there is an error in any xml file R.java is not created and thus you get this error.

Comment: @AtifFarrukh i checked them and they all seem fine

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you misunderstood the constructor for **ArrayAdapter**.

What you basically need to do is change the **R.layout.list_items** to a single element layout, just like one you would find in android.R.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Here you can see that first parameter is **context**, second one is single item layout, third (optional) is the ID of the text view you want to target with your collection of strings and the last one is the collection.

You can use your own layouts just like you tried earlier.

If you have any questions I will be happy to answer them, and also supply some code if needed.

Answer (score 1):

It look error in your xml.You can also use the simple list item if you need to display only myItems strings.

```
    String[] myItems = {"Blue", "Green", "Purple", "Red"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myItems);
```